# Raise several instances of a COM Application

Tags: c#, com, copy

I am making a C# application that makes use of the electric grid solver OpenDSS through its COM interface.

It is possible to run several standalone instances of OpenDSS .

I have implemented the ICloneable to try get several COM instances instead of one without success:

```
/// <summary>
/// Actual OpenDSS instance
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class OpenDSS_Instance : ICloneable {

    public string InstanceName { get; set; }
    private DSS DSSobj;
    private Text DSSText;
    private Circuit DSSCircuit;
    private Solution DSSSolution;
    private CtrlQueue DSSControlQueue;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="instancename"></param>
    public OpenDSS_Instance( string instancename ) {
        InstanceName = instancename;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a clone of this class
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object Clone() {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts OpenDSS
    /// </summary>
    public int Start_ODSS_Instance() {
        DSSobj = new DSS();
        if ( !( DSSobj.Start( 0 ) ) ) {
            App.func.msgboxErr( "DSS [" + InstanceName + "] failed to start.\nDoes the computer has OpenDSS installed?", "OpenDSS" );
            return 1;
        } else {
            App.func.dmessage( "DSS [" + InstanceName + "] started sucessfully" );
            DSSText = DSSobj.Text;
            DSSCircuit = DSSobj.ActiveCircuit;
            DSSSolution = DSSCircuit.Solution;
            DSSControlQueue = DSSCircuit.CtrlQueue;
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Then I create a list of copies of this class from another class like this:

```
List<OpenDSS_Instance> OpenDSS = new List<OpenDSS_Instance>();

public int startInstances() {
        //Initialize an OpenDSS instance per logical processor
        int err_num = 0;
        OpenDSS_Instance odss = new OpenDSS_Instance( "original" );

        for ( int i = 0; i < instance_number; i++ ) {
            this.OpenDSS.Add( (OpenDSS_Instance)odss.Clone() );
            this.OpenDSS[i].InstanceName = "ODSS_" + i;
            err_num += this.OpenDSS[i].Start_ODSS_Instance();
        }

        return err_num;
    }
```

My problem is that the list of instances are not copies, but refferences to the same instance.

Regardless of What I have done, How can I create several instances of a COM interface?

(I hope I have explained what the issue clear enough)

Any help is appreciated.

note: I'm not computer engineer.

Comment: You cannot deep-clone a COM interface reference.  If it is at all supported by the COM server then it will expose one of the IPersist interfaces.  Odds are low, zero if is an "Application" automation interface.  You do have to be a "computer engineer" to have a shot at it.  Ask the vendor for support first.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible then to use more than one instance of a referenced project within the soution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried actually creating multiple instances through the constructor?  It's possible that the COM server is set up to only generate one instance (either explicitly in code or through DCOM Config, in which case you may have no choice but to resort to your DLL Load solution..

```
OpenDSS_Instance odss1 = new OpenDSS_Instance( "original" );
OpenDSS_Instance odss2 = new OpenDSS_Instance( "Extra Crispy" );
```

Comment: Regrettably, it is the same, both odss1 and odss2 are ultimatelly references to the same dll.

Comment: @user3020849, that's expectable for an in-proc server. However, they should be two distinct objects. Why would you want to load the same DLL more than once?

Comment: @user3020849 but are they references to the same _object_?  If you change a value of one is it reflected in the other?

Comment: @accelent, I want to load the same DLL more than once to ave access to the solver more than once. This is usefull to use all the processor power because a single simulation only uses 14% of my i7

Comment: @DStanley, What I do is to load the same commands to define an electrical grid in all the objects in the OpenDSS lis<>, but when I send the "new circuit" command to the second object I receive a message saying that there is alredy a circuit and that I cannot create more than one. This indicates that both objects in the list are in fact pointing to the same instance of the solver.

Comment: I had the following, but I deleted it (can't remember why)   I found the solution:

Do not make copies of your DLL.

make a separated project
In that separated project make all the callings to the refferenced COM application as static and public.
Now reference that new project from the main project.
Now you are available to make several instances of that project which contains calls to your COM application.
Doing this the COM application is not refferenced but instantiated.